# Java ArrayList - I am creating an arraylist of objects but when I loop over and print it, only the last object is printed 7(size of arraylist) times

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

My problem is in my `readFiles()` method where I am creating `ArrayList<LogEntry>` records.

```
public class LogAnalyzer  {
    private static ArrayList<LogEntry> records;
    static ReadJavaDoc obj = new ReadJavaDoc();

    public LogAnalyzer() {
        records = new ArrayList<LogEntry>();
    }

    public static void readFiles(String str) throws FileNotFoundException {
        for (String s : obj.linesOfFile(str)) {
            LogEntry entry = WebLogParser.parseEntry(s);
            records.add(entry);
        }

        for (LogEntry i : records) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        new LogAnalyzer();
        readFiles(filePath);
    }
}
```

I have a `toString()` method in my `LogEntry` and by looping over, I was expecting each entry to be printed on a separate line.

However, only the last object got printed 7 times.

Other classes:

```
public class WebLogParser {
    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy:kk:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);
    private static String munchTo(StringBuilder sb, String delim) {
        int x = sb.indexOf(delim);
        if (x == -1) {
            x = sb.length();
        }
        String ans = sb.substring(0,x);
        sb.delete(0, x + delim.length());
        return ans;
    }
    public static LogEntry parseEntry(String line) {
        //Assumes line is vald and in this format:
        //110.76.104.12 - - [30/Sep/2015:07:47:11 -0400] "GET //favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 3426
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(line);
        String ip = munchTo(sb, " ");
        munchTo(sb, " "); //ignore -
        munchTo(sb, " ["); //ignore -, and eat the leading [
        String dateStr = munchTo(sb, "] \""); //]-space is intentional: eat both
        Date date = parseDate(dateStr);
        String request = munchTo(sb, "\" "); // quote-space is intentional: eat both
        String statusStr = munchTo(sb, " ");
        int status = Integer.parseInt(statusStr);
        String byteStr = munchTo(sb, " ");
        int bytes = Integer.parseInt(byteStr);
        return new LogEntry(ip, request, status, bytes, date);
    }
    public static Date parseDate(String dateStr) {
        ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
        return  dateFormat.parse(dateStr, pp);
    }}
    
public class LogEntry {

    private static String ipAddress;
    private static String request;
    private static int statusCode;
    private static int bytesReturned;
    private static Date accessTime;

    public LogEntry(String ip, String req, int stCode, int bytes, Date accTime) {
        ipAddress = ip;
        request = req;
        statusCode = stCode;
        bytesReturned = bytes;
        accessTime = accTime;
    }

    public static String getIp() {
        return ipAddress;
    }

    public static String getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    public static int getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public static int getBytesReturned() {
        return bytesReturned;
    }

    public static Date getAccessTime() {
        return accessTime;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ipAddress + " " + request + " " + statusCode + " " + accessTime + " " + bytesReturned;
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. Does `WebLogParser.parseEntry()` return a new object per invocation? 2. Is this the real code?

Comment: (i) posted code has almost more empty lines than code lines (harder to read); (ii) incomplete: no `LogEntry` code, no `WebLogParser.parseEntry()` code -- better include a [mre] !

Comment: Yes, WebLogParser.parseEntry() returns new object per invocation

Answer (score 1):

Each `LogEntry` is being printed, not just the last one. The problem is every `LogEntry` object *share the one set of fields* because the fields are `static`.

```
private static String ipAddress;
private static String request;
private static int statusCode;
private static int bytesReturned;
private static Date accessTime;
```

When a new instance is created, the field values are overwritten, so all the existing instances have their values set to the latest created instance.

Delete the `static` keyword:

```
private String ipAddress;
private String request;
private int statusCode;
private int bytesReturned;
private Date accessTime;
```

Comment: @Archismita You should delete most of your static keywords. All except the one for the `main()` method.